# after Ajax function javascript does not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript validation, that checks if input value is empty. Now I want to add a validation, that a special input is not repeating. I wrote a php function for it and also ajax. Ajax works fine, means when I enter a value, that alrady exists in database, it alerts "This No  already exists". But after that function call no javascript works.

Here is the code:

```
function checkValue(valdata){
                    $.ajax({             
                        type: "POST",
                        url:"success.php",
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        data: valdata,
                        success: function (data) {
                          if(data == 1){
                            alert ("This No  already exists. ");                             
                            return false;
                          }
                        }   
                    });         
                    return true;
                }


                if(document.getElementById("selectErrorcat").value=="selectcategory")
                {
                    alert ("Please select Category");
                }
                else if(document.getElementById("No").value ==="")
                {
                    alert ("Please enter MLS No field");
                }

                else if(document.getElementById("mlsNo").value !=="" ){

                    checkValue(formdata);
                }


                else if(document.getElementById("title_en").value ==="")
                {
                    alert ("Please enter Property Title EN field");
                }
```

After `checkValue(formdata);` javascript does not work. What is the problem?

Comment: The `else if` after `checkValue(formdata);` is not going to be executed because the `else if` that surrounds the `checkValue` call was executed.

Comment: Choose one style of brackets already. I prefer the normal style (opening bracket on new line) over Egyptian, but at least be consistent.

Comment: And it would be better not to put a bunch of blank lines between `else if`s that are connected to each other. It gives the illusion at first glance that they are independent `if`s, when they aren't.

Comment: @JonathanM yah, but how to do that aftr it the rest of js wil execute?

Comment: Are you calling the function `checkValue()`, and then expecting the code that starts with `if(document.getElementById("selecteErrorcat")...` to also be executed?  If so, it won't be, because that code is not contained within the `checkValue()` function.

Comment: @girl, please add a bit more code to your example. Show us what is after the `if else` clauses. Tell us how you know it is not executing. Show us the results you're getting and what you wanted to get.

Comment: @Jacob  if  **document.getElementById("mlsNo").value !==""** is true, checkValue function will work, if not, the next **else if** will work

Answer (score 0):

Add an error handler :

```
success: function (data) {
    if(data == 1){
        alert ("This No  already exists. ");                             
        return false;
    }
},
error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(errorThrown);
}
```